# how to convert multiple columns of pandas dataframe with object/categorical datatype to int64 in python?

Tags: python, pandas, types

I know how to convert one column by one column in pyton, but i have many many col mixed with int64 or object datatype.

In R, I can find these col index by test is.factor, then I can apply as.numeric in for loop to convert.

But I don't know how to do in Python. Please help.

If there was a way in other library, such as numpy, scipy, it would be great too.

thanks

Comment: Are you talking about `numpy`, `scipy`, or some other Python library? Could you please specify in your question, and tag it accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Just like with R you can use a simple for loop to convert column datatypes. First we check to see if the column is an object datatypes. If it is why try to convert the column. We use a try statement since the column may not be convertible to the integer datatype.

```
for c in df.columns:
  if df[c].dtype == 'O':
    try:
        df[c] = df[c].astype('int')
    except:
        print('Column',' ',c,' cannot be converted to int.')
```